# How to describe all normal subgroups of the dihedral group Dn?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

The dihedral group consists of rotations and symmetries. But the symmetry group is a group only if n is even, thus the group of rotations is a normal subgroup of the dihedral group.

So how to describe this normal subgroup(rotations) and are there any other normal subgroups of the dihedral group?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the symmetry group is a group only if n is even"?

Comment: By "the symmetry group", do you mean "the symmetric group", i.e. the group of permutations of $n$ things?  Usual language is that every object defines a "symmetry group".  The _$n$th symmetric group_ $S_n$ is then the symmetry group of a set of size $n$.  The _$n$th dihedral group_ $D_n$ is the symmetry group of a regular $n$-gon.

Answer (score 8):

I will denote by $C_n < D_n$ the subgroup of rotations.  Note a few things: $C_n$ has index $2$ in $D_n$, hence is normal, as you point out.  Moreover, $D_n$ is a semidirect product $S_2 \ltimes C_n$, where $S_2$ acts on $C_n$ by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$.  Here $S_2$ is the group of order $2$.  Note also that $C_n$ is cyclic: it is generated by a rotation by $2\pi/n$.

Let us first classify which subgroups $H$ of $C_n$ are normal in $D_n$.  Let $y\in D_n$.  Then either $y \in C_n$ or $y = xs$ for $x\in C_n$ and $s=s^{-1}$ is some particular choice of reflection.  For $h\in H$, we see that if $y\in C_n$, then $yhy^{-1} = h$; if $y = xs$ for $x\in C_n$, then $yhy^{-1} = xshsx^{-1} = xh^{-1}x = h^{-1}$.  In either case, $yhy^{-1} \in H$.  Thus every subgroup of $C_n$ is normal in $D_n$.  The subgroups of $C_n$ are classified by numbers $d$ dividing $n$.

Second, is it possible for a normal subgroup of $D_n$ to fail to be contained in $C_n$?  Yes, of course: $D_n$ is normal in itself.  Suppose that $H < D_n$ is normal and $s\in H$ for some reflection $s$.  There are two cases, depending on the parity of $n$:

If $n$ is odd, then all reflections are in the same conjugacy class.  The generator of $C_n$ ("rotation by one click") is a product of two "adjacent" reflections.  Thus if $n$ is odd, then $H > C_n$, and since $C_n$ has index $2$, $H = D_n$.

If $n$ is even, then there are two conjugacy classes of reflections: those that go through vertices of the regular $n$-gon, and those that go through edges.  These are equivalent under an *outer* automorphism of $D_n$.  Suppose $H < D_n$ is normal and $s \in H$ is a reflection.  Let $c$ denote the generator of $C_n$ ("rotation by one click"); then $csc^{-1}\in H$, and $csc^{-1}s = c^2$.  Thus $H$ contains the subgroup of $C_n$ generated by $c^2$.  If $H \ni c$, then $H = D_n$; otherwise, $H$ is generated by $s$ and $c^2$.  It is therefore a copy of $D_{n/2}$ living in $D_n$, and hence has index $2$; it is therefore normal.

In summary, the normal subgroups of $D_n$ are:

- $D_n$ itself.
- Any subgroup of $C_n$.  Theses are in bijection with the positive integers $d$ dividing $n$.
- If $n$ is even, then there are two more normal subgroups of $D_n$, each isomorphic to $D_{n/2}$.  Both contain the subgroup $C_{n/2} < C_n$.  The remaining $n/2$ elements are one or the other of the two conjugacy classes of reflections in $D_n$.