# Infinite-Representation Type Group Algebras

Tags: representation-theory

Assume that $G$ is a $p$-group, $N$ a normal subroup and $k$ a field (infinite or finite) of $char(k)=p \gneq 0$. What can we say about the representations of $G$ if we already known about the representations of $N$? For instance if the group algebra $kN$ is representation-infinite (or otherwise of infinite representation type) can we say something about the representation type of $kG$? For the moment i don't care if we need to give some further assumptions about the groups or the base field in order to answer the above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the field is infinite.

Then, there is the characterisation of representation type by Bondarenko and Drozd:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ an infinite field of characteristic $p$ (dividing the order of the group). Then
>
> - $kG$ has finite representation type if and only if $G$ has cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroups
> - $kG$ has tame representation type if and only if $p=2$ and the Sylow $2$-subgroups are dihedral, semidihedral or generalised quaternion.
> - Otherwise, $kG$ has wild representation type.

So, if $G$ is a $p$-group, then $kG$ has finite representation type if and only if $G$ is cyclic. So assume that a normal subgroup $N$ has infinite representation type, then $N$ - being a $p$-group as well - is not cyclic. Therefore $G$ can't be cyclic as subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic.

For tame representation type, a similar approach works. For generalised quaternion groups, it is known that every subgroup of such group is either generalised quaternion or cyclic (see e.g. Keith Conrad: Generalized Quaternions, Corollary 4.8). For dihedral groups, subgroups are either dihedral or cyclic (see e.g. [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595884/15416). I would guess, that a similar property holds for semidihedral groups, but these seem to be more difficult as they can have dihedral and generalised quaternion subgroups (see e.g. [enter link description here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/compute-the-subgroup-lattice-of-the-quasidihedral-group-of-order-16/))

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, i do know the above "amazing" theorem, and also the first dot is the Higman's Griterion. So can we say something like, in each dimension $d \geqslant 2$ we can construct infinite numbers of indecomposable representations?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I doubt that for each dimension $d\geq 2$ we can construct an infinite number of representations. But combining with Brauer-Thrall 2 (assuming the underlying field is algebraically closed) one can deduce that there are infinitely many $d$ such that there are infinitely many indecomposable modules of length $d$.

Comment: Can you suggest materials for amazing theorems? I cannot find them, especially for tame and wild representations of group algebras. Thank you so much.

Comment: The original reference to [Bondarenko-Drozd](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01681468). A possible textbook on the matter is Benson's ["Representations and cohomology"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/representations-and-cohomology/9EE67E1280D8DB01AAC662530799AA8E)

Comment: Thank you for your information.